# A question to show that the integral operator is a bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

This question was asked in my assignment of Functional analysis and I was not able to solve this particular problem.

> Question:(a) Show that the formula $Af(x) = \frac{1} {x} \int_{0}^x f(y) dy$ defines a bounded operator $A: L^2 (( 0,\infty)) \to L^2 ((0,\infty))$ with $||A||\leq 2$.

(b)Show that in fact $||A||=2.$

(c) Determine the adjoint operator of A.

(d) Show that $A^*A= A+A^* =AA^* .$  Deduce that the operator $U= I-A $ is unitary.

Attempt: (a) $ ||A|| \leq || \frac{1} {X} \int^x_0 f(y) dy ||\leq \frac{1} {X} \int_{0}^{x}||f(y)|| dy$ but I am not able to show that $||A||\leq 2$ because I don't understand how to find the minimum value of  integral of $f(y)$.

(b)  Due to this I am also not able to show how ||A||=2.

(c) Using the definition , I got that $A^* =  {x} ({\int^{x}_{0} f(y) dy})^{-1}$ but using this definition I am not able to show that $AA^* = A+ A^*$.

Can you please tell is my $A^*$ wrong and how to rightly calculate it?

Comment: First rework your answer to (a) but before that, write down the definitions of the norm of an operator and of the $L^2$-norm of an $f.$

Comment: @3ibfwcbi: you already got an answer. But note that the expression you wrote for $A^*$ is not even linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bound of the Hardy operator $Hf(x)=\frac1x\int^x_0f(t)\,dt$ has been discussed in several posting in MSE, for example [posting 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83946/121671) and [posting 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/126889/121671)

As for the adjoint: for $f,g\in L_2(0,\infty)$, an application of Fubini's theorem yields

\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0\Big(\frac1x\int^x_0f(y)\,dy\Big)\overline{g}(x)\,dx&=\int^\infty_0\Big(\frac1x\int^\infty_0\mathbb{1}_{(0,x]}(y)f(y)\,dy\Big)\overline{g}(x)\,dx\\
&=\int^\infty_0f(y)\int^\infty_0\mathbb{1}_{[y,\infty)}(x)\frac{\overline{g}(x)}{x}\,dx\Big)\,dy\\
&=\int^\infty_0f(y)\Big(\int^\infty_y\frac{\overline{g}(x)}{x}\,dx\Big)\,dy
\end{align}
Hence,
$$A^*g(x)=\int^\infty_x\frac{g(y)}{y}\,dy$$

---

For part (c), another application of Funibi's theorem yields
\begin{align}
AA^*f(x)&=\frac1x\int^x_0A^*f(y)\,dy=\frac1x\int^x_0\Big(\int^\infty_y\frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt\Big)\,dy\\
&=\frac1x\left(\int^x_0\frac{f(t)}{t}\Big(\int^t_0\, dy\Big)\, dt +\int^\infty_x\frac{f(t)}{t}\Big(\int^x_0\, dy\Big)\,dt\right)\\
&=Af(x) + A^*f(x)
\end{align}
Hr=er th region of integration $R:=\{(y, t):0<y\leq x, y\leq t\}$ is expressed as $R:=\{(y, t): 0<t\leq y, 0<y\leq t\}\cup\{(y, t): x<t,0<y\leq x\}$.

Similarly
\begin{align}
A^*Af(x)&=\int^\infty_x\frac{Af(y)}{y}\,dy=\int^\infty_x\frac1{y^2}\Big(\int^y_0 f(t)\,dt\Big)\,dy\\
&=\int^x_0f(t)\Big(\int^\infty_x \frac{dy}{y^2}\big)\,dt+\int^\infty_xf(t)\Big(\int^\infty_t\frac{dt}{y^2}\Big)\,dt\\
&=Af(x)+A^*f(x)
\end{align}
Here, the region of integration $Q:=\{(y, t): x<y, 0<t\leq y\}$ is split into $\{(y, t): x<y, 0<t\leq x\}\cup\{(y, t): x<t, t<y\}$.

---

Part (d) of the OP follows from (c).

Comment: Diaz  Solutions of (c) and (d)  I completely understood. Can you please give solution of (a) and (b) also? I am not able to understand them using the links mentioned . I am very new in this topic.

Comment: @3ibfwcbi: The first one is not complicated if one uses the generalized Minkowski inequality. On of the postings does that. The other part is more delicate. The second posting I refer to has several good solutions which are very interesting on their own. I suggest you take a look at them.

Comment: I looked at them but I couldn't understand. Kindly help if you have some time to spare.

Comment: Are you familiar with the generalized Minkowski inequality? If not, here is a different proof of the Hardy inequality (boundedness of $A$) that is based on (a) showing the statement for continuous functions of compact support then, and then by density arguments to extend result for all $f\in L_p$ (in your case $p=2$. That $p/(p-1)=2$ is the best constant, is more involved and I don't have the energy to rewrite my previous solution. The idea is to get a sequence of functions $f_n$  with $\|f_n\|_2=1$ and such that $\|Af_n\|_2\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{p}{p-1}=2$ (for your case $p=2$)

Comment: See [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4163455/121671) that does not use Minkowski's inequality

Comment: @OlivierDiaz How should I prove the equality of part (b)? I have done (a), thanks to your references!

Comment: @3ibfwcbi: part b is requires a little finesse. In my previous message I told you what the idea was, [posting 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/126889/121671) in my answer has a couple of solutions.